# python encoding issue or oracle issue

Tags: python, oracle

i use python socket to receive paragraph from romote side and extract message and save in my oracle database, the whole procedure is fine, but the data in orcale is unreadable, i can not figure out which makes the trouble, the paragraph or python encoding or oracle.
here is the sample paragraph

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="GBK"?>
<REQUEST>
<INFO>
<FUNNAM>GetTransInfo</FUNNAM>
<DATTYP>1</DATTYP>
<LGNNAM>直联集团管一</LGNNAM>
</INFO>
<SUMMARY>
<BBKNBR>57</BBKNBR>
<C_BBKNBR>杭州</C_BBKNBR>
<ACCNBR>571905400610608</ACCNBR>
<BGNDAT>20100525</BGNDAT>
<ENDDAT>20100528</ENDDAT>
<LOWAMT></LOWAMT>
<HGHAMT></HGHAMT>
<AMTCDR></AMTCDR>
</SUMMARY>
</REQUEST>
```

python encoding code looks like the following

```
data = data.lower().replace('encoding="gbk"', 'encoding="utf-8"')     
data = unicode(data, 'gbk').encode('utf-8') 
dom = parseString(data)
```

when i run the sql script

```
SELECT * FROM NLS_DATABASE_PARAMETERS
```

i got the result of NLS_CHARACTERSET is AL32UTF8

who can help me out. thanks in advance.